# Programm terminating with process status -1073741819 - graphics.h

Tags: c, bgi

It's my first time using graphics.h and I did everything, found drivers, included library, linker options, changed extention as cpp and when I complile the code, no error is showed just process terminated status -1073741819

```
int     init_windows()
{
    int gd = DETECT, gm;

    char driver[] = "C:\\TURBOC3\\BGI";
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, driver);
}

int     main()
{
    init_windows();
    int x = 320, y = 240, radius;

    for( radius = 25; radius <= 125; radius += 20)
        circle(x, y, radius);

    closegraph();
```

when I starts only process status -negative number is displayed and nothing more, no error, no warnning. Please help

Comment: Would you mind to tell us which compiler/linker you're using and which OS they run on, please? For me it looks like this is a source for an old -- really old -- DOS application. Oh, and BTW the source is incomplete.

Comment: Exception code `-1073741819` or `C0000005` is the code for an access violation. That means that your program is accessing (either reading or writing) a memory address to which it does not have rights. Your code looks rather like a Borland Turbo C graphics program, which will only run under MS-DOS, or in an emulator, because its graphics driver accesses video memory directly.

Comment: ...You should have checked the result of `initgraph()` too, with for example: `errorcode = graphresult(); if (errorcode != grOk) { /* an error occurred */ }`. Also your function `int init_windows()` isn't returning any value.